# Mobile HTML: keep scrolling after touch is ended

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile

I created a HTML list that I show on mobile devices:

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

When I touch display and start moving my finger this long list will be also scrolled. However, what I want to achieve is that when I move my finger away from the screen, this list should still scrolling for a moment. If you start iPhone 5S native email client, you can see such effect.

Right now, if I move my finger from the screen, iPhone stop scrolling immedeately and it doesn't feel good from usability point of view.

A CSS solution would be the best one because I try to reduce the amount of javascript code used in my mobile apps.

Comment: I guess u need some amount of javascript / jquery atleast to catch the scroll end event. After you detect it , scroll by an extra value of your choice.(say 100px)

Comment: You can use [FancyScroll.js](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/09/24/fancyscroll-js-add-an-iosandroid-overflow-scroll-effect/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
body {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

If your list is in a different scrolling container, then add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to that container as well.

Comment: Thanks myajouri!! It works when I add it to both body and ul tags.