# Foundation - Off Canvas Scroll Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm starting with Foundation and trying to get an off canvas example working.  I've been struggling because the menu opens and closes like it should, however if the page content is long and you scroll toward the bottom, when you open the menu, the focus is where you are on the page.  IE, the fixed toolbar and menu aren't fixed when open.

I've done an example on a fiddle, and would love some help!

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/caseylmanus/qb4x3e86/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas="">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
<div class="fixed">
<nav class="tab-bar">
  <section class="left-small">
    <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" href="#"><span></span></a>
  </section>

  <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
    <h1 class="title">Forest School - PARS Insight</h1>
  </section>
</nav>
  </div>

<aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
  <ul class="off-canvas-list">
    <li><label>General</label></li>
    <li><a href="#">Snapshot</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Timetable</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Homework</a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
 Long Body Content Here
```

CSS

```
.off-canvas-wrap, .inner-wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.off-canvas-wrap{  
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).foundation();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very popular Foundation issue:

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/965-fixed-menu-using-offcanvas
http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/547-off-canvas-with-fixed-top-bar
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3863
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3710

Despite of it seems that official solution doesn's exist yet I have found [this one](http://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/hApKk) ([reference](http://zurb.com/article/1350/5-ways-the-foundation-community-br-is-cru)) which looks like a nice fix of your problem.

HTML

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap">
   <div class="inner-wrap">
      <div class="header">
         <nav class="tab-bar" data-offcanvas>
            <section class="left-small">
               <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon">
                  <span></span>
               </a>
            </section>
            <section class="right tab-bar-section">
               <h1>Foundation 5 test</h1>
            </section>
         </nav>
      </div>
      <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
         <ul class="off-canvas-list">
            <li>
               <label>Foundation</label>
            </li>
            [...]
            <li><a href="#">The Psychohistorians</a>
            [...]
            </li>
         </ul>
      </aside>
      <article class="small-12 columns">
         <p>Content</p>
         <p>Content</p>
         <div data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
            <dl class="sub-nav panel">
               <dd data-magellan-arrival="build">
                  <a href="#build">Build with HTML</a>
               </dd>
               <dd data-magellan-arrival="js">
                  <a href="#js">Arrival 2</a>
               </dd>
            </dl>
         </div>
         [...]
         <p>Content</p>
         [...]
      </article>
      <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
      <footer class="small-12 columns">
         <div>...</div>
      </footer>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
article {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
article,
body,
html,
.off-canvas-wrap, 
.off-canvas-wrap .inner-wrap,
.row {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: The CSS in this Answer helped me fix my problem in Chrome. Thank You!

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate what the trick is here and why is it working?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough reputation to comment..so ill add on as an answer to Akarienta's.

I had scrolling problem on mobile browsers with the solution above.
I added `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` for the scrolling to work

```
article,
.off-canvas-wrap, 
.off-canvas-wrap .inner-wrap
  height: 100%
  width: 100%
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
article
  overflow-y: auto
```

thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407460/mobile-html-keep-scrolling-after-touch-is-ended) question